# Is it safe to use pressure-treated wood for a workbench in my shed?

Tags: wood, woodworking, safety, pressure-treated

I have some leftover PT wood from building a platform for my shed.  I'd like to use it to build a frame for a worktable that I can place inside that shed.

It will stay dry in the shed, but the shed has poor ventilation (it's basically a gigantic Rubbermaid container) and can get quite hot in the summer sun.

I plan to build the top of the table with some leftover resin/sawdust planking, so I am not worried about direct contact with the PT wood.  Should I be concerned about outgassing of noxious fumes in my stuffy shed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Offgassing has never really been a concern with treated lumber. Direct skin contact and ingestion were concerns with CCA treatment, and to a lesser degree with the products that have replaced it.

As long as you're not spending a lot of time in contact with wet wood, and as long as your pets and family members aren't gnawing on it, I wouldn't be concerned.

Comment: I tend to agree that if you aren't spending large chunks of your life in the shed this is probably fine. If the shed is your backyard writer's retreat or    there are other reasons you'd be there for many hours per year, I'd be a bit more paranoid.